# A coding problem or improper interrupt usage?

Tags: interrupt

As I should expect(?), the PIR on pin#2 should trigger the trigsensor state at any time the board is running. However, I may get one trigger then nothing else. I have a GSM shield on top of a UNO. I know that I still have some tweaking to do, but I'm trying to solve one issue at a time. Thanks for any insight. The other functions seem to perform correctly. When I enter an incorrect code, the alarms operates properly. When the interrupt is triggered, the alarm response should be the same.

```
///////////////////////// initialize & includes //////////////////////////
#include "SIM900.h"
#include "sms.h"
#include "Keypad.h"
#include <GSM.h>
SMSGSM sms;

boolean started = true;
int PIR_SensorPin = 2;
int Alarm_OutPin = 11; //green
int Light_OutPin = 12; //red
int alarm_count;
boolean volatile trigsensor = false;
const byte interruptPin = 2;
int z = 0;
int i = 0;

//////////////////////////// setup keyPad //////////////////////////
const byte ROWS = 4; // four rows
const byte COLS = 4; // four columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] =
{
  {
    '1', '2', '3', 'A'
  }
  ,
  {
    '4', '5', '6', 'B'
  }
  ,
  {
    '7', '8', '9', 'C'
  }
  ,
  {
    '*', '0', '#', 'D'
  }
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {
  6, 7, A2, A3 // row pin# on keypad to Arduino pin#, ie Row Pin #1 goes to Arduino Pin #6, etc.
}; // connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {
  3, A0, A1, A4
}; // connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );
const char PIN[5] = {
  '9', '6', '7', '9', '#'
}; // PIN number
char key_input[5] = {
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0
}; // used for comparison

//////////////////////////////// setup ///////////////////////////////////
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);  // Establish Serial connection.
  pinMode (Alarm_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (Light_OutPin, OUTPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  pinMode (PIR_SensorPin, INPUT);   // Set pinMode.
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, LOW); // Set output pins to LOW for start.
  digitalWrite (PIR_SensorPin, LOW);
  Serial.println ("GSM Shield testing."); // Serial message that GSM shield is starting up
  if (gsm.begin(4800)) {    // Set GSM shield to recommended 4800 baud rate.
    Serial.println ("Status = READY");
    digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
    // PIR as interrupt
    attachInterrupt (digitalPinToInterrupt (2), trigger, RISING);
    //attachInterrupt ((0), trigger, RISING);
  }
  //  started = false; //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  Serial.println ("System Ready, at the keypad loop!");
}

//////////////////////////////// void loop ///////////////////////////////////
void loop() {
  readKeypad();
}

////////////////////////////// void trigger ///////////////////////////////////
void trigger() {
  trigsensor = true;
  started = true;
}

//////////////////////////////// void alarm ///////////////////////////////////
void alarm() {
  Serial.println (started); Serial.println (trigsensor);
  //  digitalWrite (trigsensor, LOW);
  Serial.println("at Alarm");
  // while ((timedelay - time) > 0); Serial.println (time);  time++;
  if ((started == true) && (trigsensor == true)) {
    // (sms.SendSMS("**********", "***Motion Detected in Studio!***"));
    Serial.println ("MOTION detected: SMS Sent");
    for (alarm_count = 0; alarm_count < 5; alarm_count++) { // Cycle outputs if triggered
      digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH); delay (2000); // On/Off/On/Off/Off
      digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, LOW);
      digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, HIGH); delay (2000);
      digitalWrite (Light_OutPin, LOW); // End by turning off light
    }
    digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  }
  else { }
  readKeypad();
}

//////////////////////////////// read Keypad ///////////////////////////////////
void readKeypad() {
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (key != NO_KEY) { // if a keypad input
    key_input[z] = key;
    Serial.print("Key_input["); Serial.print(z); Serial.print("] = "); Serial.println(key);
    z++;
    if (z >= sizeof(key_input)) {
      z = 0;
    }
    switch (key) {
      case '*': // resets key_inputs to "0"
        z = 0;
        break;
      case '#': // pressed to "enter"
        z = 0;
        for ( i = 0;   i < 4 ;  i++ ) {
          Serial.print(key_input[i]);
        }
        Serial.println ("-------");
        delay(100); // for extra de-bounce
        checkPIN();
        break;
    }
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// check PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void checkPIN() {
  Serial.println ("@ checkPIN ");
  int correct = 0;
  int i;
  for ( i = 0;   i < (sizeof(PIN) - 1) ;  i++ ) {
    if (key_input[i] == PIN[i]) {
      correct++;
    }
  }
  if (correct >= sizeof(PIN) - 1) {
    Serial.print ("# correct = "); Serial.println (correct); Serial.println (sizeof(PIN) - 1);
    correctPIN();
  }
  else {
    incorrectPIN();
  }
}

//////////////////////////////// correct PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void correctPIN() {              // do this if correct PIN entered
  Serial.println ("@ correct PIN ");
  started = false;
  digitalWrite (Alarm_OutPin, HIGH);
  readKeypad();
}

///////////////////////////// incorrect PIN ///////////////////////////////////
void incorrectPIN() {           // do this if incorrect PIN entered
  Serial.println ("@ incorrect PIN ");
  started = true;
  // add time delay before alarm, via keypad??
  alarm();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the code you posted ever sets trigsensor to false, besides the initial value.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I'm not sure where it should be placed, and why??

Comment: You are correctly doing little in the ISR: set a flag telling the main program to handle something. You should unset that flag when you are done doing handling the something you needed to handle.  Guessing from your code: in the alarm() function.

Comment: It seems as if the interrupt on pin 2 is not triggering the function. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: I did make the change in the alarm function, but still not getting the interrupt to trigger.
  }
  trigsensor = false;
  readKeypad();
}

Comment: What does the signal on the interrupt pin look like? You initialize it to trigger on a rising edge -- is that what is happening with the actual signal?

Comment: I have actually tried RISING and CHANGE, with no difference. The PIR is the sensor, and it is working OK. I don't have a scope to see the signal, but it reads 5vdc on a meter. And I can get the a Serial.print to show that it is "true". The problem that I am having, referring to the original sketch posted, is that the trigger is not being seen by the "alarm" function. I am still playing around with it and may find the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You never call the alarm() function in your code. Your loop() is only calling readKeypad() and readKeypad() never looks at trigsensor. Your ISR is only changing trigsensor and started. You need to add code in your loop() function to check trigsensor and if true, call alarm() or something.

Comment: THANKS! You nailed it! Not sure how I overlooked that, but thanks for your pair of eyes. On to debugging the rest.

Comment: Mark the question as answered so that it can be useful to others!

Comment: Maybe another problem for your eyes. I seem to get the alarm to cycle regardless of the state of trig sensor and away (they should both need to be true in order for the alarm to run after an incorrect code is entered):